# Flexbox - Two column in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox in order to create two columns of three row for the Products. I looked to other similar problem on StackOverflow but the answers given didn't work for me. Could you help me please ?
Here the HTML code:

```css
Informations {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Information {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

Game {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.ProductContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

.Product {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.UpgradeContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10%;
}

.Upgrade {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE world>
<html>

<head>
  <title> World </title>
</head>

<body>
  <Informations>
    <div class="Information">Your World:</div>
    <div class="Information">Your Money:</div>
    <div class="Information">Your ID:</div>
  </Informations>
  <Game>
    <div class="UpgradeContainer">
      <div class="Upgrade">Unlocks</div>
      <div class="Upgrade">Cash</div>
      <div class="Upgrade">Angels</div>
      <div class="Upgrade">Managers</div>
      <div class="Upgrade">Investors</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductContainer">
      <div class="Product">Product1</div>
      <div class="Product">Product2</div>
      <div class="Product">Product3</div>
      <div class="Product">Product4</div>
      <div class="Product">Product5</div>
      <div class="Product">Product6</div>
    </div>
  </Game>
</body>

</html>
```

I basically want to have to the left my upgrades (Cash, angels...) and in the middle and right two column of three row of products. 
Here is my code pen to see: https://codepen.io/Tameiki/pen/oNXpNVe

Comment: Can you divide your productContainer div into two div (the columns) and inside  insert three rows of products?

Comment: I can do it but I want to understand how to correctly use flexbox :D. But thanks !

Comment: Use flex-wrap: wrap' on the parent container and 'max-width: 33.3334%' on children

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `flex-wrap` property together with setting the `flex-basis` on the child elements:

```css
.ProductContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

.Product {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 2em - 5px); /* - Margins - Borders - 1px to mitigate subpixel rounding issues*/
}
```

```html
      <div class="ProductContainer">
        <div class="Product">Product1</div>
        <div class="Product">Product2</div>
        <div class="Product">Product3</div>
        <div class="Product">Product4</div>
        <div class="Product">Product5</div>
        <div class="Product">Product6</div>
      </div>
```

---

Notice how I removed the `flex-direction:column` property: the child elements will attempt to fit in a single row, overflowing the container if necessary.

```css
.ProductContainer{
  display: flex;
  /*flex-flow: wrap;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

.Product {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  /*flex-basis: calc(50% - 2em - 5px); /* - Margins - Borders - 1px to mitigate subpixel rounding issues*/
}
```

```html
      <div class="ProductContainer">
        <div class="Product">Product1</div>
        <div class="Product">Product2</div>
        <div class="Product">Product3</div>
        <div class="Product">Product4</div>
        <div class="Product">Product5</div>
        <div class="Product">Product6</div>
      </div>
```

`flex-wrap` is what makes them start a new line instead of overflowing:

```css
.ProductContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

.Product {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  /*flex-basis: calc(50% - 2em - 5px); /* - Margins - Borders - 1px to mitigate subpixel rounding issues*/
}
```

```html
      <div class="ProductContainer">
        <div class="Product">Product1</div>
        <div class="Product">Product2</div>
        <div class="Product">Product3</div>
        <div class="Product">Product4</div>
        <div class="Product">Product5</div>
        <div class="Product">Product6</div>
      </div>
```

But how do we get only two of them per row? By telling each of the child elements to be half the row's width:

```css
.ProductContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

.Product {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  flex-basis: 50%; /*calc(50% - 2em - 5px); /* - Margins - Borders - 1px to mitigate subpixel rounding issues*/
}
```

```html
      <div class="ProductContainer">
        <div class="Product">Product1</div>
        <div class="Product">Product2</div>
        <div class="Product">Product3</div>
        <div class="Product">Product4</div>
        <div class="Product">Product5</div>
        <div class="Product">Product6</div>
      </div>
```

Unfortunately, `flex-basis` applies to the inner width of an element - including paddings, but excluding margins and borders. Usually, Flexbox tries to shrink child elements to fit the row if possible, but `flex-wrap` disables this, so we will have to adjust manually. That gets you to the code at the top.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it perfectly works ! But could you please give me more explanation about how it worked please ? I looked the doc and what you did but I don't completely understand.

Comment: Edited an explanation in.